# Show that $R$ is closed but not sequentially compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Show that $R$ is closed but not sequentially compact.

Attempt:  A subset E of a metric space X is said to be sequentially compact if and only if every sequence $x_n \in E$ has a convergent subsequence whose limit belongs to $E$. And every sequentially set is closed and bounded.

Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence then $R$ is closed since every convergent sequence $x_k \in R$ satisfies $\lim_{k → \infty} x_n \in E$. But (0, 7) is bounded and closed but not sequentially compact?

Can someone please help? Any feedback will help. Thank you

Comment: You can use a \mathbb before R to get $\mathbb R $

Comment: @gary or `\Bbb R`

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Thanks, did not know that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the sequence {$ 1,2,3,...$} in $\mathbb R$ . Does it have any convergent subsequence?

Comment: No. So I can just let $x_n = n$ and say $x_n $ does not have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes, that would work, since it is a sequence without a convergent subsequence.